# JavaFX Custom TableCell Listening

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, javafx-8, tablecell

The TextFieldTableCell, for example, responds and calls commitEdit() when you hit the enter key.

If I use a custom node to display, then how can I listen for ways to confirm an edit? For example, I have a DateTimePicker which extends a VBox. I can't add a KeyListener to a VBox.

What can I do to watch for confirmation of in-table edits? Here is what I have attempted:

```
class TableCellDateTimePicker extends TableCell<CHILD, LocalDateTime> {

    public TableCellDateTimePicker() {
        super();
    }



    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        DateTimePicker picker = new DateTimePicker();
        picker.getDatePickerField().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("PRESS");
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(picker.getValue());
            }
        });
        picker.setValue(getItem());
        setGraphic(picker);
    }



    @Override
    public void commitEdit(LocalDateTime newValue) {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        setText(newValue.toString());
    }



    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
    }

}
```

DateTimePicker:

```
/**
 * A custom DateTimePicker that lets a user select a LocalDateTime.
 *
 * @author Toni-Tran
 */
public class DateTimePicker extends VBox {

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    @FXML
    private Button showTimePickerBtn;

    private NumberPicker hourField;
    private NumberPicker minuteField;

    private ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> currentLocalDateTimeValue;



    public DateTimePicker() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource(
                ScreenPaths.DATE_TIME_PICKER));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }



    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        showTimePickerBtn.setOnAction(event -> this.showTimePicker());

        hourField = new NumberPicker();
        hourField.setBounds(0, 23);
        hourField.setWrapAround(true);

        minuteField = new NumberPicker();
        minuteField.setBounds(0, 59);
        minuteField.setWrapAround(true);

        currentLocalDateTimeValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends LocalDate> observable,
                LocalDate oldValue, LocalDate newValue) -> {
                    LocalDateTime newLDT;
                    if (newValue != null) {
                        newLDT = LocalDateTime.of(newValue.getYear(),
                                newValue.getMonth(), newValue.getDayOfMonth(),
                                hourField.getValue(), minuteField.getValue());
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(newLDT);
                    } else {
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(null);
                    }
                });

        hourField.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
                    if (currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue() != null) {
                        LocalDateTime newLDT = LocalDateTime.of(currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getYear(),
                                currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getMonth(), currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getDayOfMonth(),
                                hourField.getValue(), minuteField.getValue());
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(newLDT);
                    } else {
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(null);
                    }
                });

        minuteField.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
                    if (currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue() != null) {
                        LocalDateTime newLDT = LocalDateTime.of(currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getYear(),
                                currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getMonth(), currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue().getDayOfMonth(),
                                hourField.getValue(), minuteField.getValue());
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(newLDT);
                    } else {
                        currentLocalDateTimeValue.set(null);
                    }
                });
    }



    /**
     * Manually set a LocalDateTime value for this control.
     *
     * @param val The {@link LocalDateTime} value for this control.
     */
    public void setValue(LocalDateTime val) {
        if (val == null) {
            return;
        }
        LocalDate day = LocalDate.of(val.getYear(), val.getMonthValue(),
                val.getDayOfMonth());
        datePicker.setValue(day);
        hourField.setValue(val.getHour());
        minuteField.setValue(val.getMinute());
    }



    /**
     * Returns the currently set LocalDateTime.
     *
     * @return the {@link LocalDateTime} value of this control.
     */
    public LocalDateTime getValue() {
        return currentLocalDateTimeValue.getValue();
    }



    /**
     * Returns the Observable property of the DateTimePicker's current
     * LocalDateTime value.
     *
     * @return the Observable property of the DateTimePicker's current
     * LocalDateTime value.
     */
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> valueProperty() {
        return currentLocalDateTimeValue;
    }



    /**
     * This is triggered when the user wants to view the screen for setting a
     * certain time for their LocalDateTime.
     */
    public void showTimePicker() {
        HBox topContainer = new HBox();
        topContainer.getChildren().addAll(hourField, new Label(":"),
                minuteField);
        topContainer.setSpacing(3);
        DialogPopup.showNodeApplicationlModal(topContainer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't have time to test it out, but does `picker.setOnAction(event -> commitEdit(picker.getValue()));` work?

Comment: It doesn't have the option to use setOnAction. I have also tried using setOnMouseClicked instead. It doesn't respond to clicks at all.

Comment: Oh, wait... What is `DateTimePicker`? I misread `DatePicker`

Comment: Added the code snippet for my DateTimePicker. I actually tried adding a listener to the DTP's valueProperty, and it responded to changes. However, I'm not sure how to write commitEdit(), or updateItem(). Am I even supposed to override updateItem()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, an editable cell will display the default text when in non-editing mode and an editing control (your `DateTimePicker`) when in editing mode. Your custom cell implementation needs to handle the transition between those as well as making sure the text and value for the editing control are properly updated if the cell's item is updated.

So you should override `updateItem(...)` to update the value of the `DateTimePicker` if in editing mode (`isEditing()`) or the text if not. Override `startEdit()` to switch to show the `DateTimePicker` instead of the text, and `cancelEdit()` to switch back.

You might not need to override `commitEdit()` at all. If your column is bound to a property, the default `commitEdit()` should update that property (or you can do this in an `onEditCommit` handler registered with the column).

The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) has an example of a fully-implemented editable table cell: see listing 13.11 near the bottom.

However, you will need to invoke `commitEdit(...)` at the appropriate time. The semantics of this are a bit tricky: you probably want to commit the edit if the user presses Enter when any of the individual controls inside your `DateTimePicker` have focus, and perhaps when the focus moves away from the `DateTimePicker` entirely.

I would recommend creating an `onAction` property in your `DateTimePicker` class. This is pretty easy to do, you just have to call `setEventHander(...)` when the property changes. There's a nice example in [Richard Bair's MoneyField](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/moneyfield/) (there's a lot of stuff in that link, just look at where he creates the `onAction` handler). You can then (internally to the `DateTimePicker`) check for action events (or perhaps Enter key presses) on the individual controls and call `fireEvent(new ActionEvent(...))` when that happens. Then your table cell implementation can register an `onAction` with the `DateTimePicker` and call `commitEdit(...)`.

Committing the edit on focus loss shouldn't be much harder. Maybe expose a `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty hasFocus()` in `DateTimePicker`:

```
private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper hasFocus = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(this, "hasFocus");
hasFocus.bind(
     hourField.focusedProperty()
    .or(minuteField.focusedProperty())
    .or(datePicker.focusedProperty())
    .or(showTimePickerButton.focusedProperty()));

// ...
public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty hasFocusProperty() {
    return hasFocus.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Then your cell implementation can observe that property and commit the edit if it changes to `false`. You may have to experiment with that a bit to get it to work satisfactorily.

Comment: Excellent resources. I will look into those. One last question however: I overrode the updateItem() method like so:
`protected void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {
    if (item == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    }else{
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(item.toString());
    }
}`
 but whenever I rearrange the table columns, I end up with an added duplicate cell directly underneath it. Is my method wrong, or is this a JavaFX bug?

Comment: Set the text to null as well as the graphic when the cell is empty.

Comment: It seems that the JavaFX built in DatePicker automatically fires an event when you select a date. My custom TimePicker contains a TextField which also fires an event when you hit the enter key. Since these both reside in my DateTimePicker, it will "catch" those events and fire another event out to the TableCell that is listening to it. Where exactly does fireEvent() get picked up from? What is listening to it?